# Building a Web Audio Amplifier

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-audio-api

I'm trying to build an amplifier using a `ScriptProcessorNode` (yes, I know it is deprecated and yes, I'm fully aware of the `createGainNode`). The reason being is that the `createGainNode` is better suited to attenuate gain rather than boost it. I'm an audio engineer and I want to be able to clip my audio. I built a static version that handles a gain of at least 150 (as long as you limit the value of the floats after the boost). However, this new version, which is controlled by range input, just cuts the volume off completely.

I'm not getting any errors in the console; why is the volume cutting out?

```
<body>
<div id="button" style="background:#000;width:50px;height:50px;" onclick="connect()"></div>
<input id="range" type="range" min="1" max="128" value="1" oninput="myFunction(value)"/>
<script>
var context, 
    soundSource, 
    scriptNode, 
    buffer,
    value = 1;

    if(typeof AudioContext !== 'undefined') {
    context = new AudioContext();
}else if(typeof webkitAudioContext !== 'undefined') {
    context = new webkitAudioContext();
}else {
    throw new Error('AudioContext not supported. :(');
}

function xhr() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", 'bass.wav', true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.onload = function() {
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function onSuccess(decodedData) {
            buffer = decodedData;
        }, function onFailure() {
            alert("Decoding the audio buffer failed");
        });
    }
    request.send();
}
function connect() {
    scriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(256, 2, 2);
    scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function(audioProcessingEvent) {
        var input = audioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer;
        var output = audioProcessingEvent.outputBuffer;

        for(var channel = 0; channel < datum.numberOfChannels; channel++) {
            var I = input.getChannelData(channel);
            var O = output.getChannelData(channel);

            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                O[i] = I[i];
                O[i] *= value;         
            }
        }
    }
    soundSource = context.createBufferSource();
    soundSource.buffer = buffer;
    soundSource.connect(scriptNode);
    scriptNode.connect(context.destination);
    soundSource.start();
}
connect();
function myFunction(val) {
    value = val;
    soundSource.disconnect();
    scriptNode.disconnect();
    soundSource.connect(scriptNode);
    scriptNode.connect(context.destination);
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**
Instead of trying to build my own amplifier, I should have just used the `createGainNode` because it works exactly as intended.

**EDIT 2**
After playing with the `createGainNode` more, I figured out the original problem. In Chrome, the `createGainNode` works fine, but in Firefox, it didn't hold up as well as my amplification code. It will amplify the quieter part of the signals, but when the louder parts come in, the audio drops. Is there any work around for this? My amplification code:

```
function connect() {
    soundSource = context.createBufferSource();
    soundSource.buffer = buffer;
    volume = context.createGain();
    volume.gain.value = 1500;
    soundSource.connect(volume);
    volume.connect(context.destination);
    soundSource.start();
}
function amplify() {
    soundSource.stop();

    var left = new Float32Array;
    var right = new Float32Array;

    left = buffer.getChannelData(0);
    right = buffer.getChannelData(1);

    for(var i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
        left[i] = left[i] * 1500;
        if(left[i] > 0) {
            left[i] = 128;
        }
        if(left[i] < 0) {
            left[i] = -128;
        }
        right[i] = right[i] * 1500;
        if(right[i] > 0) {
            right[i] = 128;
        }
        if(right[i] < 0) {
            right[i] = -128;
        }
    }
    buffer.copyToChannel(left,0);
    buffer.copyToChannel(right,1);

    var amp = context.createBufferSource();
    amp.buffer = buffer;
    amp.connect(context.destination);
    amp.start();
}
```

**EDIT 3**

I've opened a bug report on bugzilla here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1233821

Comment: I'm not sure why you say "GainNode is better suited to attentuate gain than to boost it" - it's just a mathematical operation, and under the hood GainNode does precisely what you're doing here (multiplying each value).  But I don't understand what you say is going wrong here - could you elaborate on the desired outcome and current outcome?

Comment: A couple weeks ago, I tried using the createGainNode to amplify stuff and for some reason, it didn't work and I wasn't sure why. I read the docs and just blamed it on the nominal value being 1. I feel like a fool because I just tried using the createGainNode again, and it behaved exactly the way it should. I'll post an edit to clarify what should have been done. Sorry and thank you @cwilso